# Script CONTROL-M ejecutando expect

Tags: script, unix

Estoy generando un script expect para descargar archivos desde el servidor de un proveedor. El script se loguea y una vez ubicado en la carpeta correspondiente hace el get del archivo que necesita, si lo ejecuto desde el bash funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando lo intento ejecutar desde un Job de CONTROL-M.

Despues de loguearse al servidor (en el output de CONTROL-M) se ve que no ejecuta el get...

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ARCHIVO [lindex $argv 0]
   set timeout 1
   #set user [lindex $argv 0]
   #set password [lindex $argv 1]
   set user xxxxxxx
   set password xxxxxxxxxx
   spawn cadaver https://extranet.xxxxxxxx.com/webdav/Bandeja%20de%20Entrada/INFORMACION_VARIA
   expect "user"
   send "$user\r"
   expect "password"
   send "$password\r"
   expect "get archivo"
   send "get xxxxx_xxxxxxx_Cruce_20210630.csv xxxxx_xxxxxxx_Cruce_20210630.csv\r"
   send "\r"
   send "quit\r"
   interact
```

Output CONTROL-M

```
+ sh /home/u0117781/prueba/get-xxxx.sh xxxxx_xxxxx_Cruce_20210630.csv
spawn cadaver https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/webdav/Bandeja%20de%20Entrada/INFORMACION_VARIA 
Authentication required for Slide DAV Server on server `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com':xxxxxxxxx 
 
Username: xxxxxxxxxxx 
Password:  
dav:/webdav/Bandeja de Entrada/INFORMACION_VARIA/>
```